# How i can show list of objects that have no related object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a problem with django query. I'm new django programmer.

I have three models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    class Meta:
         ordering = ('dev',)
         verbose_name = _(u'Interface')

    dev = models.CharField(_(u'Interface'), max_length=5, editable=True,
          unique=True)
    enable = models.BooleanField(_(u'Enabled'), default=True)
    dhcp = models.BooleanField(_(u'DHCP'), default=False,
```

second model :

```
class Config(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       ordering = ('ip_address',)
       verbose_name = _(u'Network Configuration')
       verbose_name_plural = _(u'Network Configurations')

   device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
   ip_address = models.IPAddressField(_(u'IP Address'), unique=True)
   netmask = NetmaskAddressField(_(u'Netmask'))
   description = models.CharField(_(u'Description'), blank=True, null=True,
       max_length=255)
```

third model:

```
 class Dhcp(models.Model):

    class Meta:
       ordering = ('gateway',)
       verbose_name = _(u'DHCP Configuration')
       verbose_name_plural = _(u'DHCP Configurations')

   config = models.ForeignKey(Config)
   gateway = models.IPAddressField(_(u'Gateway'), null=True)
   dns_primary = models.IPAddressField(_(u'DNS Primary'), null=True)
   dns_second = models.IPAddressField(_(u'DNS Second'), blank=True)
   leases_time = models.IntegerField()
   nat = models.IPAddressField(_(u'NAT'), blank=True)
   max_time = models.IntegerField()
```

**And now, my question is : How do I show list of Devices that have no Dhcp configuration?**

For example: I have `Device` which has three configurations. I need to check all of configurations for that `Device` to be sure that there is no DHCP configuration and at the end show that Devices, but I dont know how I can do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
Device.objects.filter(config__dhcp__isnull=True)
```

More on queries [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)